# Is find_by_x really (mildly) deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've seen people rewriting their code from
`Model.find_by_x(x)`
to
`Model.find_by(x: x)`
([example](https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/f02d25566d42f06d2ceea596ff9823d5ad06da67)) and I'm wondering if it's time to do some housekeeping.

Is `find_by...` really deprecated? (Some evidence / discussion would be good.)
This [Rails commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/04cda1848cb847c2bdad0bfc12160dc8d5547775) hints that it is. Also here in the [ActiveRecord::Base doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) that this commit changes it is mentioned to be "mildly deprecated".

The extracted [dynamic_finders gem](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders) claims that it isn't: "Note that find(primary_key), find_by..., and find_by...! are not deprecated."

And also in the [4.0 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations): "All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize that this answer is lacking the evidence / discussion, but I wanted to just say that it makes sense to me that `Model.find_by_attribute` and the like *should* be deprecated -- i.e. you should treat them as such and move away from them even though they're not officially deprecated. The reason being that these methods must go through method_missing to do their magic. So they're not as fast as using `find_by(x: y)` which, under the scenes, just uses ARel: `where(x: y).take`. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @pdobb, it does. I follow your reasoning. It's a layer of overhead that adds no benefit to readability so moving away makes sense regardless.

Comment: I was interested in the performance aspect of these finders (which led me to this post) and did a quick benchmark below

    `Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|`
        `x.report("find_by") { 1000.times { Model.find_by(my_field: "value") } } `
        `x.report("find_by_attr") { 1000.times { Model.find_by_my_field("value") } }`
    `end`
`
                     `user     system      total        real`
   ` find_by      0.610000   0.250000   0.860000 (  1.276131)`
    `find_by_attr  0.560000   0.040000   0.600000 (  1.032426)`

Sorry about the formatting !